# Avoid column names on empty results in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, label, formula, crystal-reports-2008, empty-list

My question it's quite simple.

Suppose I have a "StoredProcedure" that gives me a result of a table with 2 columns, say: "Name" and "Surname".

I want to show the table only if the result set is not empty.

If I drag&drop the "Name" and "Surname" fields to the "Details" section, it automatically generates in the Header section the name of those columns, but if the result set is empty, I still see the column names. What I want is to make the column names dissapear if there isn't any data to show.

Any idea of how to do this?, it sounds very reasonable so I guess the solution is simple, but I don't know it

Answer (score 0):

I now realized this question is answered in other question I made.
[Conditional printing depending of empty or null value in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567918/conditional-printing-depending-of-empty-or-null-value-in-crystal-reports)

I guess that setting a conditional value on the column labels with the "Count()" function (I guess should be one), would make the job done.

```
If Count(someFieldOfTheResult) == 0 THEN 
    notShowLabel 
ELSE 
    showLabel
```

Comment: I hope someone could confirm that my supposed answer is correct.